# CopyOnWriteArrayList: understanding small detail

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` methods that mutate its state (`add`, `set`, etc) acquire the lock following way:

```
final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
lock.lock();
```

Why does it save `this.lock` into a local variable? `this.lock` is declared final so it can't change anyway. Why couldn't we just write `this.lock.lock()`? Does it have some implication  on concurrency or is it just a matter of taste?

Here is the [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#CopyOnWriteArrayList.set%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) to source code.

Comment: Yes, I think the idea is to not block.  So that way updates never block when someone is iterating through the list (which might take a while).  Not blocking can be a big deal in concurrency performance.

Comment: @markspace The question is why save the lock in a `final` local variable?

Comment: Yeah I'm actually confused.  Now I think he's asking why create a local variable for `lock`.  I think the OP should clarify.

Comment: C.f. this code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#CopyOnWriteArrayList.set%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

Comment: I thought the question was clear, but I clarified it anyway.

Comment: You should add more code to your example;  it is not clear that those variables are local and not instance fields.  99% sure this is just taste, there's no difference in code operation if the instance variable (`this.lock`) is used instead.